# Open Remote website Dialog box in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-web-site-project

It seems that opening a remote website feature is removed in Visual studio 2015. it was present in 2013. as shown in the open website dialog boxes below. 
How can one open a remote website residing on a web server in 2015?

**Open Website Dialog box in Visual studio 2013/2102**

[image: Open Website in Visual studio 2013/2102]

**Open Website dialog box in Visual Studio 2015**

[image: Open Website dialog box in Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Do you mean remote debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Remote Website" deployment option requires FrontPage Server Extensions, as the dialog states. FPSE enabled WebDAV-like publishing and the Web Folders feature in Windows.

FPSE was last released in 2002 and is now completely obsolete. Very few webhosts support FPSE thesedays so it would be of little use even if VS still supported it.

FTP deployment is far more supported and conceptually far more simpler - so that's why.

WebDAV is a nice design in abstract, but when implemented server-side it's far too complicated to setup and maintain, and doesn't work with modern web-applications because of conflicts with resource-paths. FTP "just works".